# How we can migrate a SQL Server database to AWS EC2 Instances without having any down time and having all security measures in place

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am trying to migrate my on premise SQL Server database to an AWS EC2 instance Microsoft 2019 AMI. I don't want to use AWS RDS.

What is the best possible way to do this?

And how to automate MSSQL db migration from on premise to AWS EC2 instance Microsoft 2019 AMI ?

Comment: You need a consultant not SO

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will depend **greatly** on your application, current deployment topology and business needs & requirements.

Given you explicitly stated that RDS is not an option - you cannot use AWS Database Migration Service which would've made your life easier. It seems you want to utilize AWS EC2 as "yet another VMs", however one should know that EC2 has quirks and requires designing around these, which can be different from on-prem deployments. For instance, you have to plan around AZs (balancing multi-AZ deployments for HA purposes), EC2 machines may be restarted due to underlying hardware issues - you have to be able to bring services up with data available (decouple instance & storage), etc.

Generally speaking, when planning these kind of migrations you need to perform (on a high level) the following steps (**Important** These are generic points and not SQL server specific):

- Set-up new deployment of the DB on EC2 (Ideally you want it in a private subnet, but it depends on your infrastructure, networking setup and where application that accesses DB is running).
- Set-up a continuous sync of the data from On-Prem to Cloud one (For instance, one could join a replication group and have master node On-Prem at start).
- Ensure you can connect to the Cloud DB from your application and add Cloud instance to the list of known servers to connect to.
- Once everything is working, fail-over master to the cloud - now all writes should be going to the cloud instance.
- Detach cloud instance from on-prem and remove on-prem from list of known servers.

This is a very generic list of things one would do for pretty much any DB migration. Obviously you have to perform tests and fine-tune the process (and most likely add more steps) depending on your specific needs and setup.